# Generating pdf using phpexcel

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

I am creating pdf file by using phpExcel and I have 24 columns in the data from the database and only 17 columns are in the pdf and remaining is cut off.Is there any way to have all 24 columns in the pdf file?How can I achieve it?

Comment: What PDF rendering engine are you using?

Comment: From the [DomPDF Q&A](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ) - `Q: I have a big table and it's broken!
A: This is fixed in versions 0.4 and higher. Previous versions did not support tables that spanned pages.` What version of DomPDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mPDF is working fine in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

I set page orientation to landscape. Unfortunately, it was the only solution I could found.